# Functionality for next and previous for the larger image

Tags: jquery

Can any one please help me out to add the functionality for next and previous for the larger image

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
        var src = this.src.replace('thumb', 'large');
        $("#largeImage").fadeOut(function() {
            this.src = src;
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    }); 
});

<div id="page">
    <div id="gallery">
        <div id="panel">
            <img id="largeImage" src="images/image_01_large.jpg" />
        </div>    
        <div id="thumbs">
            <img src="images/image_01_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" />
            <img src="images/image_02_thumb.jpg" alt="2nd image description" />
            <img src="images/image_03_thumb.jpg" alt="3rd image description" />
            <img src="images/image_04_thumb.jpg" alt="4th image description" />
            <img src="images/image_05_thumb.jpg" alt="5th image description" />     
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="next">Next</a> 
    <br />
    <a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What issues are you encountering currently with the code you have so far?

Comment: <div id="page"> <div id="gallery">  <div id="panel">        <img id="largeImage" src="images/image_01_large.jpg" />     </div>
    <div id="thumbs">
        <img src="images/image_01_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" />
        <img src="images/image_02_thumb.jpg" alt="2nd image description" /> <img src="images/image_03_thumb.jpg" alt="3rd image description" /><img src="images/image_04_thumb.jpg" alt="4th image description" />
        <img src="images/image_05_thumb.jpg" alt="5th image description" /></div></div><a href="#" id="next">Next</a><br /><a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a></div>

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question.

Comment: I want to add the next and prev button to the larger image. I am unable to write its functionality. Can you please help me out.

Comment: hi Darin, I want to add the next and prev button to the larger image. I am unable to write its functionality. Can you please help me out.

Comment: why invent the wheel when it already exist? take a look at [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) which is a jQuery for image scrolling

Comment: Hi ClydeFrog, I should not use any kind of plugins. thats the case. I am unable to retrieve the source of larger images when I am clicking on next and prev.

Comment: are the "Next" and "Prev" links supposed to change the large image or are you supposed to click on the thumbs to change the large image?

Comment: Hi ClydeFrog, Clicking on the thumbnail the larger should be shown which is working in my script. But the need of next and prev is for larger image. We have to show the next and prev to the images which are in div#panel not for thumbnails. Just like facebook,if you are selecting an image you will get a larger image popup with next, prev and close button

Comment: Look this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMyGE/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to add the functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function loadSlide(nSlide)
    {
        $('#thumbs img.current').removeClass('current');
        $(nSlide).addClass('current');

        var src = $(nSlide).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large');
        $("#largeImage").fadeOut(function() 
        {
            this.src = src;
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    }

    $('#next').click(function()
    {   
        var cSlide = $('#thumbs img.current');
        if($(cSlide).next('img').length > 0)
            var nSlide = $(cSlide).next('img');
        else
            var nSlide = $('#thumbs img:first');

        loadSlide(nSlide);
    });

    $('#prev').click(function()
    {
        var cSlide = $('#thumbs img.current');  
        if($(cSlide).prev('img').length > 0)
            var nSlide = $(cSlide).prev('img');
        else
            var nSlide = $('#thumbs img:last');

        loadSlide(nSlide);
    });

    $('#thumbs img').click(function(){
        loadSlide(this);
    });

    loadSlide($('#thumbs img:first'));
});
```

Comment: hi Aatif Farooq, There is an issue again, the image is sliding on selecting the next and previous but the issue is if we are selecting a thumbnail then the larger image shown should be corresponding to the thumbnail and then if am clicking the next button then the larger image should show the next image. Now what the issue is if am refreshing the browser and am selecting the last thumbnail and then am clicking to next button then it should show the first image but its showing the second one. Can you please fix this issue.

Comment: please, use the current code and remove your jquery code from the page. It will work now.

Comment: Thanks Aatif Farooq, its working but initially I just want to show the thumbnails after selecting any thumbnail then the larger images starts to show. Can you please help in this also

Comment: Aatif Farooq Thank you very much I completed the task. thank you very much for supporting me and helping me